# How do i parse Registry Value of type REG_SZ to a variable?

Tags: c++, registry

Tried this function but the output is junk values

```
WCHAR vcVER[256];
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\14.0\\VC\\Runtimes\\x64"), _T("Version"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &vcVER, NULL);
```

Reg Path: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64`

Key name: **`Version`**

Value   : **`v14.0.24215.01`**

I need to able to parse that value

Comment: Parse it how?  Do you need to split it at the `.`'s?

Comment: I just need the whole value in a string

Comment: There's no point in using `TCHAR` stuff if the array is going to be wide anyway. In any case, using straight wide strings is recommended nowadays.

Comment: _"I just need the whole value in a string"_: `std::wstring strVER(vcVER);`

Comment: @ManjunathBabu You have it in `vcVER`.  Just look up how to convert a `WCHAR*` to a `std::wstrign` or `std::string`.

Comment: On topic, you're misusing the function: *The pcbData parameter can be NULL only if pvData is NULL.*

Comment: @chris : How do i handle pcbData param?

Comment: @ManjunathBabu, I have nothing extra to offer beyond the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724868\(v=vs.85\).aspx). It points to a variable that contains the byte count of the buffer, and it includes the null terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the size of the buffer through a variable. Try this:

```
WCHAR vcVER[256];
DWORD dwSize = _countof(vcVER);
RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
_T("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\14.0\\VC\\Runtimes\\x64"), 
_T("Version"), RRF_RT_REG_SZ, NULL, &vcVER, &dwSize);
```